# currentTime set to different value after loadmetadata event during seek

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, audio-streaming, media-source

I am currently on an adventure with my sanity at stake where I try to simply play an mp3 file on my web-application. This mp3 is loaded chunk-wise in order to make the experience more responsive.

Even though the documentation of the MediaSource API is just remarkably, almost violently, useful and hundreds of well explained examples pave the way towards salvation, I find myself not able to make everything work properly.

The last issue I am facing is the seeking-functionality. The simple idea I had for this feature is to simply kill everything that's alive, burn everything down and revive again. To be more precise, if the user seeks, I stop the machinery and start playing everything from scratch, but with the desired offset (in seconds).

*Everything* is working so far except one last thing: `currentTime`, gets set to a different value after I have set it to the time that the user requested.

The track continues playing as expected but **the problem is** that `currentTime` is what's being used to visualize the current location within the track for the user.

This is how the events take place before and after the user seeks

```yaml
[play-click]    <--- User clicks play button
 :
[timeupdate]    currentTime: 00.01
[timeupdate]    currentTime: 00.02
[timeupdate]    currentTime: 00.03
[seek-click]    <--- User seeks, stop() is called and then playFrom(seconds)
[loadstart]     currentTime: 33.33  # This is the (correct) time set in playFrom(seconds)
[loadmetadata]  currentTime: 10.12  # Now the time gets set to this (wrong) value
[seek]          currentTime: 10.12  # The triggered seek event comes in
[seeked]        currentTime: 10.12  
[canplay]       currentTime: 10.12
[playing]       currentTime: 10.12
[timeupdate]    currentTime: 10.13  # Track continues to play correctly but this value is still wrong
 :
```

This is how seeking takes place:

```js
public play(track: Track) {
  this.track = track;
  this.playFrom(0);
}

public seekTo(seconds: number) {
  this.stop();
  this.playFrom(seconds);
}

public stop() {
  this.logger.debug('Stop ..');
  this.sourceBuffer.abort();
  this.audioObj.pause();
  this.removeEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, this.audioEventsHandler);
  this.audioObj = null;
  this.sourceBuffer = null;
  this.mediaSource = null;
}
```

Now, the `playFrom(seconds)` method is a bit more complicated than that but all it really does is re-create everything that I just destroyed:

```js
private playFrom(seconds: number) {

  this.logger.debug(`Start playing from ${seconds.toFixed(2)} seconds`)

  // [:] (collapsed some less important code here)

  // Create the media source object
  this.mediaSource = new MediaSource();
  this.mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', this.onSourceOpen);

  // Create audio element
  this.audioObj = document.createElement('audio');
  this.audioObj.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.mediaSource);
  this.audioObj.currentTime = seconds;
  this.addEvents(this.audioObj, this.audioEvents, this.audioEventsHandler);

  this.logger.debug(`Object-url: ${this.audioObj.src}`);

  this.state = {currentTime: seconds, playing: true};
}
```

How can I get the correct current-time here?

I tried another idea where I was tring to create and add a new `SourceBuffer` to the `MediaSource` and let it play the audio from there but I wasn't able to do that either.

Comment: I am going to do something similar. @Stefan did you succeed in your implementation? Can you share me your repository link if it's open source?r

Comment: @ashuvssut my advice is to not implement this on your own. Convert your mp3 into a fragmenten mp4 using ffmpeg and use something like the shaka player for playing back your audio or stream.

Comment: I have created a Mp4 player here. The prototype seems to work just fine. I have published a stable release in npm

You can test out the demo player locally. Visit the repo https://github.com/stacknide/mp4box-apps and checkout the demo-player folder

Answer (score 1):

What is the duration reported by the MediaSource (or by the media element) at the time of issuing the seek to the media element? If it is infinite, you may need to use the {set,clear}LiveSeekableRange APIs in MSE to let the implementation know if you wish to let the player seek beyond the currently buffered media's highest presentation end time. Alternatively, you could possibly *set* the MediaSource duration before seeking to be something finite, but at least as high as the highest currently buffered media presentation end time.

Comment: It may also help to not "burn down everything"; there is complexity in the extended HTMLMediaElement in how to handle a seek when readyState is not >= HAVE_METADATA. If all you mean to do is abort current appends and start buffering freshly, then do the abort(), then remove everything (sourceBuffer.remove(0,MediaSource.duration)), then proceed. It's common for players to not remove media explicitly, but leave it to MSE to evict if needed at the start of each appendBuffer(). So figuring out why you're needing to resort to "burning it down" at the start of every seek would probably also be good.

Comment: I attempted the same experiment as @Stefan. After seeking to a new time (which was not yet buffered), I followed your advice: attempted to abort, remove the entire buffer, and then append the corresponding buffer at that seeked time. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me; the SourceBuffer closed. I'm feeling quite uncertain about implementing a seeking feature using MSE. Seeking did not work for a seeked time point that was not yet buffered. Matt, do you have any suggestions on what I should try next? Any directions would be very helpful